# What steps should I follow while doing this project?

Tags: python, image-processing

I was very confused while doing the project and realized that I needed help. First of all I have 2 images and one of these images contains highway with empty and the other one contains highway with cars on it. I am asked to find the number of vehicles in the second picture using OpenCv and these two images, but I don't know which paths to follow. More precisely, I don't know how to use the two images together.(Using Python)

Comment: `I am asked to find the number of vehicles in the second picture using OpenCv` Why do you need the first picture at all?

Comment: This is where I'm confused as well. Only one image has a vehicle and what do I do with the other image?

Comment: Subtract the two images and find the number of gaps

Comment: this is a homework/exam task. review your course's syllabus. consider what you're supposed to have learned by now. consider the topics from the lecture. simple subtraction is too simple to give good results. "background subtraction"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest

1. Reducing the frist picture from the second.

   1.1. Since they are the same (as far as I understand), you will get 0 values everywhere but the cars.
2. Use `cv2.findContours` on the result on step 1. to get the contour of each car,
3. Count the number of contours, should match the number of cars